# Getting a row based on the condition

Tags: php, mysql, datatable, conditional-statements, crud

Been circling around trying to find a solution to this problem. I already searched for it and had no luck finding one.

I have 2 tables which are related

entry table

| id | entry_name | entry_qty | entry_group | entry_owner | high_bet | early_finish |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test1 | 3 | 1 | Test1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | Test2 | 3 | NULL | Test 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | Test3 | 3 | NULL | Test3 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | Test4 | 3 | NULL | Test 4 | 0 | 0 |

entries table

| id | parent_id | enties_name | entries_weight | fought |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Test1__1 | 1011 | NULL |
| 2 | 1 | Test1__2 | 1011 | NULL |
| 3 | 1 | Test1__3 | 1011 | NULL |
| 4 | 2 | Test2__1 | 1011 | NULL |
| 5 | 2 | Test2__2 | 1011 | NULL |
| 6 | 2 | Test2__3 | 1011 | NULL |
| 7 | 3 | Test3__1 | 1011 | NULL |
| 8 | 3 | Test3__2 | 1011 | NULL |
| 9 | 3 | Test3__3 | 1011 | NULL |
| 10 | 4 | Test4__1 | 1011 | NULL |
| 11 | 4 | Test4__2 | 1011 | NULL |
| 12 | 4 | Test4__3 | 1011 | NULL |

This is the query I want to achieve but not sure how to convert it to mysql or php script:

randomly select(1) `parent_id` from `entries` if `entry.early_finish` is 1 (prioritize) or 0 (less priority but will be picked when there is no 1 left) then add a value to **fought** if picked.

Then;

Randomly select(1) `parent_id` from `entries` if `entry.early_finish` is 1 (prioritize) or 0 (less priority but will be picked when there is no 1 left) AND `entry.group_id` is not equal to the first query then add a value to **fought** if picked.

This way, 2 random rows will be picked and this will be the match.

Hoping someone here can save me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    es.id,
    es.parent_id,
    e.entry_name as parent_name,
    es.entries_name,
    es.entries_weight,
    es.fought
FROM
    entries es
LEFT JOIN
    entry e
ON
    es.parent_id = e.id
WHERE
    e.early_finish = (
        CASE
            WHEN (SELECT count(id) FROM entry WHERE early_finish=1) > 0 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    )
AND
    es.fought = 0
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer. Answers which consist only of code are often improved by also providing an explanation of the techniques used in the solution. See "code-only answers" discussions [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290231/12567365) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405981/12567365) for more about this.

Comment: You can also take the [tour] and read [answer] for more guidance.